# Why PhpStorm pop Navigation Bar does not work?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have some problem with Navigation Bar. For example, if I open that bar and want to go some folder and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will disappear.

I can't navigate between folders

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 1) What is your OS and IDE version? 2) That Navigation Bar -- is that fixed one (always visible) or a pop up (only visible on demand)?

Comment: os: UBUNTU 19.04. ide: PHPStorm 11.0.3. and... yes navigation bar only visible on demand

Comment: Version 11? That's soon to be 4 years old version (next one was 2016.1 .. and latest is 2019.2). It must have been fixed since then, as it works just fine here in latest version (I'm on Windows though). I have found few tickets, but they refer to different versions (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90564) or even a JDK (PhpStorm now uses own JDK (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212540). Try the latest version -- see how it behaves there (you can run different versions in parallel as they use diff config folders): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/

Comment: oh sorry my bad... it was runtime version. ide version is 2019.2.1

Comment: In such case it should be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1762 (it has quite a few duplicate tickets) -- the fix is for own JDK and current status is "On review" so I suggest to wait for next minor version

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for help... i will follow that issue

Comment: If you want, and if that JDK build is already available, you can try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12836-choose-runtime/ plugin to download and use different JDK build (mainly for test purposes / critical issues)

Comment: I cannot guarantee for 100% that this JDK will fix the issue for you, but based on the duplicate tickets it should be the right one